4.1 3d modeling - cutting through/separating touching limb parts
Beginner here, I'm sculpting a body and 3 of its parts (knees, mtp joints, heels) melted into each other.
The goal is to separate them in order to complete retopology and eventually rig.I don't understand how to separate them, I tried the bisect tool but I failed.

If someone could enlighten this poor noob it would be so appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

You have Snapping turned on (horseshoe icon icon the top toolbar) which may have caused your issue in the first place?
